# Reboot encrypted phone without having to enter password and PIN after crash

Tags: encryption, reboot, crashes

Last week my phone crashed when using Amaze File Manager. This Xperia Z1 Compact phone with Android 5.1 is encrypted. It rebooted automatically. I see the encryption lock and expect a password request. Then I see the normal lock screen. After a while I see that the network is up without having to enter the PIN to unlock the SIM card. Only one device manager is active, F-Secure Antivirus. Normal restarts require me to enter both the encryption code and PIN.

- Phone crashes
- Reboots without having to enter encryption code
- SIM is unlocked automatically
- No device manager is active that should do this

How can this happen? Shouldn't a crash result in a compleet restart? Can you explain this?